# Make array type from type

Tags: swift, types, casting

I am getting a lot of data from my server.

To serialize it I use [ModelMapper](https://github.com/sunshinejr/Moya-ModelMapper). I have lots of `Mappable` objects, so I need a function that would be able to map any kind of mappable data. Something like this:

```
func serializeData(of type: Mappable.Type) -> [Mappable]? {
     return try? response?.map(to: [type].self)
}
```

My issue is that `map(:)` method requires `[Mappable].Type` as input. `[type].self` however is `[Mappable.Type]`. I am getting lost here. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the type as `foo.Type` is a very *objective-c-ish* pattern.

In Swift I'd prefer a generic solution, something like

```
func serializeData<T : Mappable>() -> [T]? {
     return try? response?.map(to: [T].self)
}
```

or still *swiftier*

```
func serializeData<T : Mappable>() throws -> [T] {
     return try response?.map(to: [T].self) ?? []
}
```

Comment: I'm always impressed with your responses. Do you have a Swift blog or anything similar?

Comment: @D.Greg Thanks. No, I haven't.